# Permitir solo decimales con coma(,) en lugar de (.) Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, regex

He encontrado un script perfecto para mi en el que controlas los valores introducidos tanto picados como pegados. También es sencillo cambiar el numero de decimales permitidos.

Pero soy incapaz de modificar el delimitador . por ,

El script en cuestión es el siguiente: http://jsfiddle.net/dj3r6hb2/1/

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: puedes usar la propiedad [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema debes cambiar la condición de la captura del keypress caso de que:

---

La longitud de newValue sea igual a 1 y el caracter sea igual a ",".

El nuevo carácter no sea un número y sea diferente de ","

hasDecimalPlace retorne cierto

---

Como ha comentado Roger Torné, debes cambiar en la función hasDecimalPlace el punto del **value.indexOf** por una coma.

Esto también deberías hacerlo en la expresión regular del paste.

```js
$(function () {

    $('#salary').bind('paste', function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!/^\d*(,\d{1,2})+$/.test($(self).val())) $(self).val('');
        }, 0);
    });
    
    $('.decimal').keypress(function (e) {
        var character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
        var newValue = this.value + character;
        if ((newValue.length == 1 && character == ',') || (isNaN(character) && character != ',') || hasDecimalPlace(newValue, 3)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
        var pointIndex = value.indexOf(',');
        return  pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Name</b>

<input type="text" id="name" />
<br/>
<b>Salary</b>

<input type="text" id="salary" class="decimal" />
```

Comment: Maravilloso! Había aplicado la propuesta anterior de Roger, que para nada iba mal encaminado, pero me faltaban algunos cambios que en tu respuesta me han salvado la vida! Muchas gracias a los dos!

Comment: Si te sirvió  acepta la respuesta. Dandole  al check que hay en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Aunque seguro que existen alternativas más elegantes, puedes recurrir a cambiar la función `hasDecimalPlace` que es donde determina si el valor contiene un punto. Aquí lo puedes cambiar por una coma (línea `var pointIndex = value.indexOf(',');`).

```
function hasDecimalPlace(value, x) {
    var pointIndex = value.indexOf(',');
    return  pointIndex >= 0 && pointIndex < value.length - x;
}
```